# Custom output column based on whether a value exists in any record of another, unrelated table

Tags: sql, case, exists

I've got a bunch of tables, and I'm trying to pull various pieces of information from each of them. One of the pieces of information I need is if a customer is subscribed to the newsletter, but there is no linking data between the two tables apart from the email address. So, I'm trying to show a custom column, (e.g. SubscribedToNewsletter), which shows whether a customer's email address exists in the Subscriptions.Email values (i.e. True/False).

```
Customer
===============
Email

Subscriptions  
===============
Email
```

I've tried things using `CASE` and `EXISTS` to try and forge a custom column based on whether a value exists in the column of the other table, but it's not producing any fruit.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Subscriptions.Email = Customer.Email THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Subscriptions ON 1=1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customer WHERE Subscriptions.Email = Customer.Email)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a correlated sub-query to count each customer's number of subscriptions:

```
select c.*,
       case when (select count(*) from Subscriptions s
                  where s.Email = c.Email) > 0 then 'True'
            else 'False'
       end
from customers c
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I realised a big mistake I was making was joining to the table, which gave me roughly 3000 records (100~ customer records * 30~ Subscription records).